Looking for an alternative solution to this problem without trigonometry
Diagonals of the convex quadrilateral $ABCD$ intersect at point $O$. A point $K$ is chosen on $BD$ in such way that the area of $ABCD$ is $k$ times the area of triangle $ABK$. Find $KD$ if $AO = m$, $CO = n$, $BD = d$.

The Trigonometry proof I know:

Calculate the diagonal $AC$: $AC = AO+OC = m+n$.
Let $\alpha = \angle AOD$. Then the area of $ABCD$ can be expressed as $S_1 = \frac{1}{2}AC\cdot BD\cdot \sin\alpha = \frac{1}{2}d(m+n)\sin\alpha$.
Therefore, the area of triangle $ABK$ will be equal to $S_2 = \frac{1}{k}S_1 = \frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{1}{2}d(m+n)\sin\alpha = \frac{1}{2k}d(m+n)\sin\alpha$.
Construct altitude $AH$ of triangle $ABK$. Then the area of triangle $ABK$ will be also expressible as $S_2 = \frac{1}{2}BK\cdot AH$.
Consider triangle $AOH$. In it, $\sin\alpha = \frac{AH}{AO} = \frac{AH}{m}$. Therefore, $AH = m\sin\alpha$.
Substitute this expression for $AH$ in formula of $S_2$, to get $S_2 = \frac{1}{2}BK\cdot m\sin\alpha$.
From two ways to express the same area of triangle $ABK$, we get: $\frac{1}{2k}d(m+n)\sin\alpha = \frac{1}{2}BK\cdot m\sin\alpha$. From here, we get $d(m+n) = kBK\cdot m$, and finally $BK = \frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{d(m+n)}{m}$.
Then $KD = BD-BK = \boxed{d - \frac{1}{k}\cdot\frac{d(m+n)}{m}}$

I am looking for an elementary geometry proof without trigonometry.

As $AO:OC=m:n$, let $\text{area}(\triangle ABD)=mx$, $\text{area}(\triangle BCD)=nx$
Thus $\text{area}(ABCD)=(m+n)x$
Thus, $\text{area}(\triangle ABK)=\frac{m+n}{k}x$
Using areas $\triangle ABD$ and $\triangle ABK$, $$\frac{BK}{BD}=\frac{m+n}{mk}$$
Thus $KD=BD-BK=BD(1-\frac{m+n}{mk})=d(1-\frac{m+n}{mk})$


As $AO:OC=m:n$, let $\text{area}(\triangle ABD)=mx$, $\text{area}(\triangle BCD)=nx$ --- why that?


@Rusurano Hint: think about the ratio of the heights of $BCD$ and $ABD$ with respect to base $BD$

Try once for yourself, and if you still can't proceed, please comment.
